# Change the background colour of DIV if another function is executed

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that looks for words typed in to a TextArea field in a form.
What I need to do is if the function is executed change the background colour of another DIV.

My function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#FeedBackComments').highlightTextarea({

    words: {
    color: '#ADF0FF',
    words: ['one','two','three',' four']
    },
    debug: false,
    caseSensitive: false
    // change the colour of DIV
    });
});
```

Any advice and help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
$("divid").css("background-color","red");  /*or your color of choice*/
```

or you could try

```
$( "body" ).contents().find( "divid" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, I tried that prior to posting but it produces a syntax  error.

Comment: try this $( "body" ).contents().find( "divid" ).css( "background-color", "red" );

Comment: @DCJones, fiddle is not working, can you add a working version

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('#textarea_id').keyup(function() {
   var text = $(this).val();

   if (['word1', 'word2'].indexOf(text) != -1) {
       $('#div_id').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
   }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwff7ygv/

Comment: @DCJones Please don't forget to mark Sayak's answer as accepted by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left. That's the best way to thank people on Stack Overflow for an exemplary answer!

Comment: @DCJones i played with that fiddle and i can't get it to turn red? how does it work?

Comment: @RachelGallen it triggers only if the text contains word1 or word2.